# How to change element color in Periodic Table?

Tags: replacement, color, curated-data, chemistry

The command

```
ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"]
```

generates a periodic table.

As I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I asked myself how to change the color of each cell in the periodic table, (hydrogen -> pink, iron, gray etc.). I want to do it in the simples way.
How can I do that?

Since

```
ElementData[Element, "IconColor"]
```

is protected I dont have any idea.

Comment: `ColorData["Atoms","Panel"]` and `ElementData[element,"IconColor"]` are not the same colors in general. There are slight differences.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
myAtoms = {"H", "Li", "Na"};
defCols = myAtoms /. ColorData["Atoms", "ColorRules"];
newCols = {Pink, Yellow, LightBlue};
ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"] /. Thread[defCols -> newCols]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit:**

Changing the font color isn't related to the `ColorRules`, but to the special formatting used by the `Panel`. So it's cumbersome, but you can see that Mma uses a similar approach to the following, since the only font colors that get changed are those of the three elements I selected:

```
newCols = {Red, Darker@Darker@Yellow, Blue};
nt = ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"] /. Thread[defCols -> newCols];

gl = GrayLevel;
nt /. {r : RGBColor@c__, e_[{r1__, Inset[Style[r2__, gl@_], r3__]}, r0__]} :> 
      {r, e[{r1, Inset[Style[r2, ColorConvert[r, "Grayscale"] /. gl@a_ :> gl@UnitBox@a], r3]}, r0]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Welcome back with a +1 :)

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks! Too much boring work lately

Comment: Leave those boring stuff and come have fun here.

Comment: Thanks @belisarius. I Tried 

      Hcolor = "Cr" /. ColorData["Atoms", "ColorRules"];
      Ocolor = "Os" /. ColorData["Atoms", "ColorRules"];
      ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"] /. {Hcolor :> Pink,Hcolor :> Pink}

To change more than one color. Is it an uggly way?

Comment: @Zhozer See edit

Comment: Wow, fantastic. Thanks @belisarius.
I thought it would be more difficult.

Comment: @Zhozer It's usually better to delay the "accept" at least one day. Somebody could come up with a better/ more complete answer ...

Comment: Ok. ^^ @belisarius

Last question: how to change the element color (they are all black or white)? Depending on the color used it is interesting to change it. I checked all the properties of ColorData, but I couldn`t find how.

Comment: @Zhozer See edit, please

Comment: Thanks, @belisarius. :)
With graylevel the result is much better than setting specific colors for the elements. Nice.

Answer (score 13):

I know you said you didn't want to reinvent the wheel, but sometimes, it's fun to do so.  The code below creates a palette with a Periodic Table and a few buttons to make useful tool tips.  It shows how one might change the colors based on properties grabbed from `ElementData`.  Note that this code was written for version 9, and if you wish to use it in version 10, you must first execute:

```
SetSystemOptions[SystemOptions["DataOptions"] /. True -> False]
```

Pardon some of the obfuscatory symbols; the code originates from my (failed) attempt to create a tweetable interactive periodic table.

```
CreatePalette[Manipulate[
  Column[{
    Evaluate[Grid[Table[{i, j}, {i, 7}, {j, 18}]]] /.
      Thread[
       Evaluate[
         Partition[
          MapThread[ElementData[#1, #2] &, 
           Transpose[Tuples[{Range[112], {"Period", "Group"}}]]], 
          2]] -> Evaluate[
         Item[Tooltip[ElementData[#, "Symbol"], 
             ElementData[#, popup]], Background -> color[#], 
            Frame -> True] & /@ Range[112]]] /. {{_, _} -> ""},
    Grid[{Item[
         Tooltip[ElementData[#, "Symbol"], ElementData[#, popup]], 
         Background -> color[#]] & /@ Range[57, 70], 
      Item[Tooltip[ElementData[#, "Symbol"], ElementData[#, popup]], 
         Background -> color[#]] & /@ Range[89, 102]}, Frame -> All]
    }, Alignment -> Center, Spacings -> {0, 1}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 10}],
  {{popup, "Name", "Show me the:"}, {"Name", 
    "AtomicNumber" -> "Atomic number", "AtomicMass" -> "Atomic mass", 
    "ElectronConfigurationString" -> 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(-\)]\) config"}},
  {{color, bcd, "Color by"}, {ncd -> Tooltip["None", "No color"], 
    bcd -> Tooltip["Block", "s,p,d,f"], 
    pcd -> Tooltip["Phase", "Solid, Liquid, Gas"], 
    mcd -> Tooltip["Metal", "Metal, Nonmetal, Metalloid"]}},
  Initialization :> {
    ncd[x_] := White;
    bcd[x_] := 
     ColorData[11][
      ElementData[x, "Block"] /. {"s" -> 1, "p" -> 2, "d" -> 3, 
        "f" -> 4}];
    pcd[x_] := 
     ColorData[13][
      Switch[ElementData[x, "Phase"], "Gas", 6, "Liquid", 2, "Solid", 
       1, _, 5]];
    mcd[x_] := 
     Which[#[[1]], LightBlue, #[[2]], LightGreen, #[[3]], LightRed] &[
      MemberQ[ElementData[x, "Memberships"], #] & /@ {"Metal", 
        "Nonmetal", "Metalloid"} ];
    }], WindowTitle -> "Periodic Table"]
```

[image]

The part that is relevant to you is in the `Initialization` rule where I define `ncd`, `bcd`, `pcd`, and `mcd`.  `ncd` sets all elements to the same color, `bcd` uses the block pulled from `ElementData`, and the last two pull characteristics from `ElementData` as well, using that information in slightly different ways.  Hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: @bobthechemist, can you find a way to display all or most of the features at the same time?

Comment: @alancalvitti I'm not sure I follow.  If you mean coming up with color scales for all of the properties provided by `ElementData` then yes, in principle, but that would require a a bit of thought. A generic `elementcolordata` function would need to handle missing data, devise a way to sort non-numeric data, and probably decide whether linear or logarithmic color scaling is appropriate.

Comment: @bobthechemist, btw, +1, not necessarily by color but any other visualization method, eg icons or other graphical markup. Also there seem to be alternative periodic tables and layouts, including spiral based. Jan Boeyens describes 4 tables in his Chemistry from First Principles. It would be nice to relate them.

Comment: @alancalvitti I see.  Yes, I have given some alternate visualizations some thought, but non of that is ready for prime time yet.

Comment: Wow, really cool, @bobthechemist . :)

Answer (score 7):

This example picks the colors according to atomic weight, which are loaded from `ElementData[]`. Like belisarius's answer, it generates a list of rules to replace colors

[image: Rules created in the first line]

which is then applied to the pane.

```
Rule @@@ Transpose[{ColorData["Atoms", "ColorList"] , 
   ColorData["NeonColors"][QuantityMagnitude@ElementData[#,"AtomicMass"]/200] &
   /@ Flatten@ColorData["Atoms", "Range"]}]
ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"] /. %
```

[image: Resulting pane]

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that there are two natural approaches: (1) modifying color rules *before* the panel is created or (2) post-processing the output to replace recognizable colors.  belisarius already showed a method for the second so I shall address the first.

**This method is *more robust* than the post-processing one.**  See the final example below.

## Modifying the color rules

The color rules are loaded through this call:

```
DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`getColorSchemeData["Atoms"]
```

From the definition:

```
DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemes
```

The data looks like this:

[image]

For easy replacement of colors I propose:

```
subColors[cdat_List, {rules__} | rules_Rule] :=
  MapAt[ReplacePart[MapAt[PositionIndex @ cdat[[4]], 1] /@ {rules}], cdat, 5]
```

(Ignore any messages; I recommend putting `Off[Pattern::patv]` in your kernel `init.m`.)

This allows us to replace rules in the data with e.g.

```
subColors[data, {"H" -> Pink, "Fe" -> Gray}]
```

We can now use this replacement function in a wrapper function like this:

```
SetAttributes[withScheme, HoldFirst]

subColors[cdat_List, {rules__} | rules_Rule] :=
  MapAt[ReplacePart[MapAt[PositionIndex @ cdat[[4]], 1] /@ {rules}], cdat, 5]

withScheme[body_, scheme_, rules_] :=
  With[{CS := DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemes},
    ColorData[1, 1] (*preload*);
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{CS, ColorData},
      Unprotect[ColorData]; ColorData[scheme] =.;
      CS = MapAt[subColors[#, rules] &, CS, Position[CS, {{scheme, ___}, __}]];
      body
    ]
  ]
```

Now:

```
withScheme[
  ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"],
  "Atoms",
  {"H" -> Pink, "Fe" -> Gray, "Ti" -> Red, "Hs" -> Blue}
]
```

[image]

This is intended for use with any Named color scheme.  Because colors are modified before they are used this will even affect applications of the colors where they are later modified, e.g. with `Darker`:

```
withScheme[
 Graphics[{ColorData["Crayola", "SkyBlue"] ~Darker~ #, Rectangle[]}] & /@ {.1, .5, .8},
 "Crayola",
 "SkyBlue" -> Red
]
```

[image]

Comment: **Note:** Caching bug corrected.

Comment: @Zhozer You're welcome.  I was wondering if anyone had noticed this answer.