# Changing the atom color for plotting xyz-files

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color, chemistry

*Mathematica* takes the standard color code for atoms when plotting an *.xyz file, but I want to customize the color for the specific atoms.

I really become desperate as I did not get it so far.

Example:

```
Import["ExampleData/caffeine.xyz"]
```

[image: caffeine]

It doesn't really matter which colors are used. I just need to know how to change the default ones.

Answer (score 13):

One can use the (undocumented?) option `ColorRules`:

```
Import["ExampleData/caffeine.xyz", 
 ColorRules -> {"H" -> Red, "C" -> Black, "N" -> Darker@Green, "O" -> White}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Addendum:** Other options may be found here: `` Options[Graphics`MoleculePlotDump`iMoleculePlot3D] ``.  Note: The option `ColorFunction` seems to be unimplemented.

Comment: Related: [24045](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24045).

Comment: Great find!  For the particular problem I can't imagine a better answer.  I still do like the generality of my approach and I hope people find value in it elsewhere.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks. I liked your answer so much, I nearly gave up after reading it.  But I was curious how the bonds are determined, when bond data is missing in the xyz format. So I kept looking.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
t = Import["c:\\work\\temp\\1.xyz"];
```

[image]

```
allColors = {};
(*get all colors from Graphics3D*)
Scan[If[MatchQ[#, RGBColor[__]], AppendTo[allColors, #]] &, t, 
  Infinity];
allColors = DeleteDuplicates[allColors]
(*{RGBColor[0.65, 0.7, 0.7], RGBColor[0.4, 0.4, 0.4]}*)
(*replace all obtained colors with any another*)
replaceRules = MapThread[Rule, {allColors, {RGBColor[0.4, 0.4, 1], RGBColor[0.4, 1, 1]}}];
t /. replaceRules
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This question is closely related to: [How to change element color in Periodic Table?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57133/121) and my solution there works here as well.  However thanks to this question I realized that it had a bug which I have now fixed.

An example for your application:

```
(* please load code from linked answer *)

withScheme[
  Import["ExampleData/caffeine.xyz"],
  "Atoms",
  {"H" -> Blue, "O" -> Yellow, "N" -> Orange}
]
```

[image]