# Change the colors of individual atoms in a .mol or XYZ file

Tags: graphics3d, color, chemistry

Similar to ([Changing the atom color for plotting xyz-files](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65492/changing-the-atom-color-for-plotting-xyz-files)), I want to take a molecule and then simply change the colors of individual atoms. I don't want to change all atoms of a type to a color (say, make all carbons purple) but individual atoms and bonds.

Comment: Take a look at the `InputForm` of the molecule and try changing some of the options manually.

Answer (score 5):

With caffeine as the example molecule

```
molecule = Import["ExampleData/caffeine.xyz"]
```

one can find all spheres that represent the single atoms using

```
sphereList = Cases[molecule[[1, 4, 2]], _Sphere]
```

> ```
> {Sphere[1,24.],Sphere[12,24.],Sphere[14,24.],Sphere[15,24.],Sphere[16,24.],Sphere[17,24.],
>  Sphere[18,24.],Sphere[22,24.],Sphere[23,24.],Sphere[24,24.],Sphere[3,34.],Sphere[5,34.],
>  Sphere[6,34.],Sphere[7,34.],Sphere[10,34.],Sphere[13,34.],Sphere[19,34.],Sphere[20,34.],
>  Sphere[2,32.],Sphere[4,32.],Sphere[8,32.],Sphere[21,32.],Sphere[9,31.],Sphere[11,31.]}
> ```

As the new color I define

```
newColor = RGBColor[0, 0.58, 0]
```

Now one can pick a specific atom out of the list of spheres, e.g. the the rightmost atom, and change its color using

```
molecule /. {x___, color_RGBColor, s___Sphere, Sphere[12, 24.], z___} -> 
             {x, color, s, newColor, Sphere[12, 24.], color, z}
```

> [image: Caffeine1]

or use a `Manipulate` to pick the atom and to choose the color

```
Manipulate[
 molecule /. {x___, color_RGBColor, s___Sphere, sphere, z___} -> 
             {x, color, s, nc, sphere, color, z},
 {sphere, sphereList}, {nc, Green}]
```

> [image: Caffeine2]

If you want to change the color of multiple atoms:

```
Manipulate[
 Fold[ReplaceAll, molecule, {{x___, color_RGBColor, s___Sphere, sphereList[[#]], z___} -> 
      {x, color, s, nc, sphereList[[#]], color, z}} & /@ spheres],
 {{spheres, {1}}, Range[Length@sphereList], ControlType -> CheckboxBar}, {nc, Green}]
```

> [image: MultiColorCaffeine]

A version to change the color of some atoms and single bonds

```
cylinderList = Cases[molecule[[1, 4, 2]], _Cylinder];
Manipulate[
 Fold[ReplaceAll, 
  Fold[ReplaceAll, 
   molecule, {{x___, color_RGBColor, s___Sphere, sphereList[[#]], z___} -> 
    {x, color, s, ncS, sphereList[[#]], color, z}} & /@ spheres], 
   {{x___, color_RGBColor, s___Cylinder, cylinderList[[#]], z___} -> 
    {x, color, s, ncC, cylinderList[[#]], color, z}} & /@ cylinders],
 {{cylinders, {1}}, Range[Length@cylinderList], ControlType -> CheckboxBar},   
 {{spheres, {1}}, Range[Length@sphereList], ControlType -> CheckboxBar}, 
 {ncS, Darker@Green}, {ncC, Darker@Green}]
```

> [image: AtomsBonds]

And thanks to the comment by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) a version that changes the color of the selected atoms and their bonds

```
Manipulate[
 Fold[ReplaceAll, 
  molecule, {a : Sphere[#, _] | Cylinder[{#, _} | {_, #}, _] :> {nc, a}} & /@ atoms],
 {{atoms, {1}}, Range[Length@sphereList], ControlType -> CheckboxBar}, {nc, Darker@Green}]
```

> [image: AtomsAndBonds]

Comment: Nice implementation.  I wish Wolfram would admit that there exists in this world multiple bonds.  It makes creating one's own molecule viewer a necessity at present.

Comment: +1. This seems a more straightforward substitution that captures an atom and its bonds: `With[{n = 8}, molecule /. a : Sphere[n, _] | Cylinder[{n, _} | {_, n}, _] :> {Purple, a}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for your substitution code. I added a version of it to the code. I also added a `Manipulate` to choose single bonds.

Comment: @bobthechemist Part of the problem seems to be that the XYZ file format does not include bond information (right?).  The MOL2 format does have it, but showing bond multiplcity does not seem to be possible.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Right, XYZ doesn't provide that information.  I'm complaining about how `ChemicalData` knows bond multiplicity `ChemicalData["Caffeine", "EdgeTypes"]` but refuses to show it `ChemicalData["Caffeine", "MoleculePlot"]` in 3D.  The "StructureDiagram" seems to be chemically correct.