# How can I swap two colors in a bullet gauge?

Tags: graphics, color

I want to swap two colors in a bullet gauge.

Is this possible to do this without using something similar to

```
BulletGauge[{1, 1.8, 3, 3.4, 4, 5}, {2.4, 2.9}, {0, 3.5, 4.8}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  GaugeStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Purple, Orange, LightBlue}]
```

[image]

Comment: What is undesirable about the solution you yourself suggested?

Comment: @Quantum_Oli I think  that is smarter use the a swaping of the 5th color with the 6th color, using the numser 5 and 6 of a list, and not defining a color with RGB, which is longer.

Comment: Related: [(57133)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57133/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we somehow [know in advance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124025/121) the colors that are being used a post-processing replacement is possible.

```
swapIndexed[i_, c1_, c2_] := {# -> #2, #2 -> #} & @@ (ColorData[i] /@ {c1, c2})

BulletGauge[
  {1, 1.8, 3, 3.4, 4, 5}, {2.4, 2.9}, {0, 3.5, 4.8}
  , ImageSize -> Large
] /. swapIndexed[63, 5, 6]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Description

Simply change the order of colors in `GaugeStyle`

### Example

```
BulletGauge[{1, 1.8, 3, 3.4, 4, 5}, {2.4, 2.9}, {0, 3.5, 4.8}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 GaugeStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Purple, Orange, LightBlue}]

BulletGauge[{1, 1.8, 3, 3.4, 4, 5}, {2.4, 2.9}, {0, 3.5, 4.8}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 GaugeStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Purple, LightBlue, Orange}]
```

### Output

[image: ex1]
[image: ex2]

Comment: Can I ask why your rolled back my edit when it provided a fuller answer?

Comment: @Feyre the edit you've made did indeed provide a solution. Therefore I thought it would be best if you'd add it as such which would grant you extra reputation points as oppose of me taking credit for your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

without using a swaping function.... (I don´t remeber/know native swaping function).....

```
gs = Table[ColorData[63, i], {i, 1, Length [ColorData[63, "ColorList"]]}]

BulletGauge[{1, 1.8, 3, 3.4, 4, 5}, {2.4, 2.9}, {0, 3.5, 4.8},  ImageSize-> Large, GaugeStyle -> gs]
temp = gs[[5]];
gs[[5]] = gs[[6]];
gs[[6]] = temp;
gs

BulletGauge[{1, 1.8, 3, 3.4, 4, 5}, {2.4, 2.9}, {0, 3.5, 4.8}, ImageSize -> Large, GaugeStyle -> gs]
```