# Periodic table with color code

Tags: plotting, color, legending, curated-data, chemistry

Is it possible to do this table (from [here](http://www.pi5.uni-stuttgart.de/common/show_file.php/finished_thesis/146/beschraenkt/thesis.pdf)) in *Mathematica*?

[image: periodic table]

In this table, the color code indicates the element’s dipolar character $(~ m\mu_m^2)$ in atomic units.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes

Comment: Why did you not provide a source fo this table?

Comment: Why the downvoter? This is the Figure 1 of [this](http://www.pi5.uni-stuttgart.de/common/show_file.php/finished_thesis/146/beschraenkt/thesis.pdf) thesis. Sorry for that.

Comment: @user6014 Thank you for that. Do you have any hint on how to do this?

Comment: It seems that this question was not well accepted. Please close it and then delete. Sorry.

Comment: [A closely related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57133)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

where I used the list `dipolar` from Okkes's answer

```
dipolar2 = Flatten[Reverse @ 
   FoldPairList[TakeDrop, dipolar, {15, 15, 17, 17, 18, 18, 8, 8, 2}]]
```

and `ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"]` modified to remove `Eventhandler`s and to replace abbreviations for some elements to match the table in OP:

```
panel = Replace[ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"][[1, 1]] /. 
   EventHandler -> (# &), {"Lv" -> "Uuh", "Ts" -> "Uus", "Og" -> "Uuo", 
  "Nh" -> "Uut", "Fl" -> "Uuq", "Mc" -> "Uup"}, ∞]  ;
```

with color function `"Rainbow"` (with purple tones clippped):

```
ClearAll[dipF, cF, reColorF] 
elements =  Cases[panel, Style[s_String, ___] :> s,  ∞];
dipF = # /. Dispatch[Thread[elements -> dipolar2]] &;
cF = ColorData["Rainbow"][Clip[Rescale[#^(1/3), 
    MinMax[(dipF /@ elements)^(1/3)]], {1/10, ∞}]] & ; 
reColorF[highlighted_: {}] := # /. {_RGBColor, {r_Rectangle, 
       Inset[Style[a_, b___], c___]}} :> 
  {EdgeForm[a /. {Alternatives @@ highlighted -> {Opacity[1], Magenta, 
           Thickness[.004]}, _ -> None}], cF[dipF @ a], 
  {r, Inset[Style[Column[{Style[a, White, FontSize -> Scaled[.02]], 
           Style[dipF@a, FontSize -> Scaled[.015], FontColor -> White]}, 
           Alignment -> Center, Spacings -> .15], b], c]}} &;

lgnd = BarLegend[{cF, {0, 25000}}, "TickSide" -> Left, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 200}];
legend = RawBoxes @ Replace[ToBoxes[lgnd], Rule[FrameTicks, _] :> 
    Rule[FrameTicks, False], ∞];  
highlighted = {"H", "He", "Li", "Na", "K", "Rb", "Cs", "Ca", "Sr", 
   "Cr", "Dy", "Er", "Yb"} ;

Legended[Show[reColorF[highlighted]@panel  , ImageSize -> 700], legend]
```

> the picture above

Comment: fix two lines of code: add a square bracket in the line `dipF = # /. Dispatch[Thread[elements -> dipolar2] ]&;`, remove the square bracket in the line `dipolar2 = Flatten[Reverse @ FoldPairList[TakeDrop, dipolar, {15, 15, 17, 17, 18, 18, 8, 8, 2}]]`

Comment: Thank you @AlexTrounev.

Comment: Personally I'd have skipped the `{"Lv" -> "Uuh", "Ts" -> "Uus", "Og" -> "Uuo"}`, since you are replacing the currently accepted symbols with the old deprecated ones.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less, good point.  I too would have skipped the replacement (out of laziness) if the task weren't to replicate the picture in OP.

Comment: Well, then you'll need to replace `Thread[{"Nh", "Fl", "Mc"} -> {"Uut", "Uuq", "Uup"}]` too for complete accuracy. ;)

Comment: @J.M right again; I missed those. Thanks.

Comment: @kglr First of all, thank you for your code. But, I don't know why your code doesn't work in my 11.0 version. Here is the erro message:

`Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {H,He,Li,Be,B,C,N,O,F,Ne,Na,Mg,Al,Si,P,S,Cl,Ar,K,Ca,Sc,Ti,V,Cr,Mn,Fe,Co,Ni,Cu,Zn,Ga,Ge,As,Se,Br,Kr,Rb,Sr,Y,Zr,Nb,Mo,Tc,Ru,Rh,Pd,Ag,Cd,In,Sn,<<66>>}->{1,0,7,0,1,0,126,144,76,0,23,0,3,0,279,289,142,0,39,0,65,85,18,1872,1373,2010,2122,1467,64,0,8,0,674,711,320,0,85,0,128,162,258,3455,2450,4952,3705,0,108,0,13,0,<<68>>} cannot be combined.`

Comment: @Dinesh, this works in version 11.3. It seems that in your version the seventh row in `ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"]` has fewer than 17 elements.

Comment: I'm using 11.2 version now and it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @DineshShankar, you need v 11.3.

Comment: @kglr Okay, I'll test it in version 11.3 soon. Thanks.

Comment: @kglr It worked perfectly in version 11.3. Thanks a lot. Do you know how to put the caption $m\mu_m^2$?

Comment: I got it using  `lgnd = BarLegend[{cF, {0, 25000}}, "TickSide" -> Left, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 200}, 
   LegendLabel -> 
    Placed[MaTeX["\\quad m\\mu_m^2", Magnification -> 1.5], Top]];`

Comment: I have a new problem now. I would like to change the position of the BarLegend.

Answer (score 9):

**Edit 2:**

```
dipolar = {327, 413, 4135, 4372, 2715, 0, 11907, 7026, 24700, 25100, 
    21017, 12593, 4128, 0, 29, 200, 2242, 1509, 831, 74, 0, 7446, 
    4473, 15893, 16250, 13359, 8196, 2703, 0, 252,
    223, 0, 471, 96, 0, 6800, 9720, 9936, 4496, 280, 0, 32, 0, 2592, 
    2637, 1176, 0, 133, 0, 317, 65, 0, 4655, 6848, 6920, 3121, 197, 0,
     23, 0, 1881, 1881, 840, 0, 85, 0, 128, 162, 258, 3455, 2450, 
    4952, 3705, 0, 108, 0, 13, 0, 1096, 1148, 508, 0, 39, 0, 65, 85, 
    18, 1872, 1373, 2010, 2122, 1467, 64, 0, 8, 0, 674, 711, 320, 0, 
    23, 0, 3, 0, 279, 289, 142, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0, 126, 144, 76, 0, 1, 0};
minMax = MinMax@((dipolar)^(1/3)) // N;
data = Delete[Join @@ Table[{i, j}, {j, 10}, {i, 1, 18}], 
   Join @@ {List /@ Range[2], List /@ Range[18, 20], 
     List /@ Range[36, 54], List /@ Range[57, 57], 
     List /@ Range[75, 75], List /@ Range[129, 138], 
     List /@ Range[147, 156], List /@ Range[164, 179]}];
data2 = Flatten /@ Partition[Riffle[(dipolar)^(1/3), data], 2];

Legended[Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black}], 
     ColorData["DarkRainbow"][Rescale[First[#], minMax]], 
     Rectangle[Rest[#]], Black, 
     Text[First[#]^3, Rest[#] + {0.5, 0.5}]  } & /@ data2], 
 BarLegend[{"DarkRainbow", minMax}, 
  Ticks -> {{0, 0}, {10, 1000}, {17.09975946676697`, 
     5000}, {21.54434690031884`, 10000}, {29.24017738212866`, 
     25000}}]]
```

[image]
**Edit:** Just replace dipolar with the original data and change $\{0,1\}$  with `min` and `max` of dipolar data..

```
dipolar = RandomReal[1, 118];

data = Delete[Join @@ Table[{i, j}, {j, 10}, {i, 1, 18}], 
   Join @@ {List /@ Range[2], List /@ Range[18, 20], 
     List /@ Range[36, 54], List /@ Range[57, 57], 
     List /@ Range[75, 75], List /@ Range[129, 138], 
     List /@ Range[147, 156], List /@ Range[164, 179]}];

data2 = Flatten /@ Partition[Riffle[dipolar, data], 2];

Legended[Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black}], 
     ColorData["ThermometerColors"][Rescale[First[#], {0, 1}]], 
     Rectangle[Rest[#]]} & /@ data2], 
 BarLegend[{"ThermometerColors", {0, 1}}]]
```

[image]
**Original answer:**

Here is starting point. Now you need to paint each individual  square with the dipolar data..

```
data = Delete[Join @@ Table[{i, j}, {j, 10}, {i, 1, 18}], 
   Join @@ {List /@ Range[2], List /@ Range[18, 20], 
     List /@ Range[36, 54], List /@ Range[57, 57], 
     List /@ Range[75, 75], List /@ Range[129, 138], 
     List /@ Range[147, 156], List /@ Range[164, 179]}];
Graphics[Rectangle[#] & /@ data]
```

[image]

Comment: Hum. Thank you for your help. I thought there was another way to do the color bar. I think there must be another solftwere that does this automatically.

Comment: @DineshShankar here is a way to get color bars: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html

Comment: Woa.. thanks. This is simpler than I thought.